# KVM VM obtaining duplicate IP address for strange MAC address

Tags: kvm-virtualization, dhcp

I have a ubuntu KVM host on which Ubuntu virtual machine is created in virt-manager.

The VM is obtaining 2 different IP's from DHCP server which is running on Windows Server. 1st IP address lease looks normal, but the second IP lease shows strange long identifier:
[DHCP leases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOxMq.png)

The VM is configured to use bridge in network manager:
[virt-manager NIC configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjOXN.png)

The VM is configured to obtain IP from DHCP server in netplan yaml file:

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    enp1s0:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: false
```

I have read that the long MAC address can be caused by wrong send dhcp-client-identifier.
I have tried to set dhcp identifier to MAC address showed in NIC settings in virt-manager (this is the normal MAC address visible also in the DHCP leases) but it did not help. I have also tried to set it to "hardware" and it did not help neither.

When I have tried to switch dhcp4 to false in netplan, the strange long MAC address is not present. When the DHCP is off in netplan, the "normal" MAC address lease is still present in DHCP manager. The VM of course does not have access to the Internet, when the dhcp is off. However, switching the dhcp4 on in netplan enables access to Internet, but the second IP lease with the strange long MAC address presents.

Why does virt-manager send a request for dhcp when dhcp4 is off in the netplan?

How to convince dhcp client to ask for IP address with normal MACaddress?

edit - added "ip a" output from the VM:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,DYNAMIC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 52:54:00:eb:f8:c5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.62.73/24 metric 100 brd 192.168.62.255 scope global dynamic enp1s0
   valid_lft 647758sec preferred_lft 647758sec
inet6 fe80::5054:ff:feeb:f8c5/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
link/ether 02:42:75:fa:e5:5d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Those two IP addresses are assigned to `enp1s0` in the VM guest?

Comment: No, only IP4 assigned to long uid is vissible in "ip a" on enp1s0. Also enp1s shows MAC address in right format but in DHCP leases there is the long uid for IP 192.168.62.73. I have added "ip a" output to the post